# Improving the quality of OCR using pytesseract

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract to recognize text from this image but I'm unable to get satisfactory results.
I've tried a number of things to make it easier for the tesseract to recognize the text. My tesseract version is 5.0

1. Taken color out of the image, leaving it only with black and white
2. Converting it into grayscale and then reading it
3. Attempted a gaussian blur
4. Blew up the image to ensure that it could read it more efficiently
5. Tried an inverse threshold to make the images stand out more but still no positive outcome.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPkW2.png)
[Black and White Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km98b.png)

[Black and White Binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjwBv.png)

Comment: It should be enough to do just #1, but you'd need all symbols to be black & background white. If you've done so - please attached that black & white image.

Comment: @DmitriiZ.thanks for the reply, i've added the image

Comment: I can see in your image that some symbols are white instead of black - that's most likely causing issues with OCR. Try to binarize your image so that all test is black and all backgorund is white (without any boards around symbols)

Comment: @DmitriiZ.I've added the third image too, but tesseract still doesn't recognize all the numbers

Comment: On all your images x2 and x7 are white symbols with black borders. This is most likely causing ORC issues.

Comment: Maybe this will help somewhat?  tesseract imagename.png results.txt --psm 11

Comment: @Tyson sorry i don't understand what you mean by that, are you saying use the option --psm 11? Everytime i make a change, i run it through all the options from --psm 1 to --psm 13

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Would you recommend that i separate all the images out rather than keeping them in a single image? Like have a separate image with x2 and x7

Comment: @WorkerBee Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Sorry for the vague comment. It looks like you already tried that though. I don't have any other ideas :(